# Debugging a WCF Service in Visual Studio 2012 (variable not declared or inaccessible)

Tags: .net, wcf, debugging, visual-studio-2012

I have problems in debugging a WCF Service in Visual Studio 2012. The client application and the WCF Service are in the same Solution, both configured for debug.
The debugger breaks/steps into the WCF Service successfully but I can't have a watch on any variable declared in the service.

> 'Variable' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its
>   protection level.

I can have a watch to any variable passed as an argument from the client application.